# What is C# equivalent of TSQL's "IN" operator? What are the ways to check if X exists in X,Y,Z in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

What are the ways to check if `X` exists in `X,Y,Z` in c#? 
For eg:

```
X=5;
```

I want to check if X's value matches  any of the comma separated values..

```
if(x in (2,5,12,14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new int[] { 2,5,12,14}.Contains(x);
```

Comment: Actually this came to my mind(I should have mentioned it in my question, my mistake) . But I was hoping I could find a more convenient way. Even if its through Linq.

Comment: Not convenient enough? What do you want?

Comment: lol its pretty convenient. Lets just say I am looking for alternatives just to gain knowledge. +1

Comment: Oh I just realized that I can do that in just one line instead of two. 
`if (new int[] { 2,5,12,14}.Contains(5))` I am going to mark your post as answer. If i dont get a better answer.(which I am not likely to get)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the inline for frequently run code, such as in a loop, as it will construct a new array each time, better off with a local variable containing the array/list

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
list.Contains(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Linq.Contains()` what you searching for

```
// Create List with three elements.
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("cat");
list.Add("dog");
list.Add("moth");

// Search for this element.
if (list.Contains("dog"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("dog was found");
}
```

There are two methods `Linq.Contains()` method and an extension  `Linq.Contains<int>`

```
        var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        // Use extension method.

        var stp = new Stopwatch();
        stp.Start();
        bool a = list.Contains<int>(7);
        stp.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time in extenstion method {0}", stp.Elapsed);

        stp.Restart();
        // Use instance method.
        bool b = list.Contains(7);
        stp.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time in normal method {0}", stp.Elapsed);
```

> Performance benchmark : The version specific to List i.e, `list.Contains(7);` , found on the List type definition, is faster. I tested the same List with the two Contains methods.

Answer (score 0):

You may use .Contains method. e.g. listItems.Contains(x)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `in` operator in C#, but you can implement an extension method to make the code more readable.

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T val, params T[] values) where T : struct
    {
        return values.Contains(val);
    }
}

//usage: var exists = num.In(numbers);
```